# Random number with fixed number of digits, greater than 32Bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, ios8, digits

I need to generate a random number with fixed length in iOS 7-8, for me it is 13 digits. All the answers here lead to using `arc4random_uniform`, but this returns only a 32Bit value. 32Bit has a maximum of 10 digits, thus I need something that returns bigger values.

Any recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: 1) Generate a random number with 10 digits. 2) generate a random number with 3 digits 3) Concatenate

Comment: Thanks @Zaph, haven't seen this question!